# How to fill this pencil shape with gradient in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, gradient

I've been struggling to fill this entire pencil-like shape with this gray gradient. It always stops bluntly at the tip, leaving it empty. How do I get it to fill all the way from the point?
[image]

Comment: it is hard to know what is going on without more information like knowing how your shape was created- it seems that either you have 2 shapes there- a rectangle and a triangle- so the triangle is not filling with the gradient or if it is truly only one shape then possibly  you have 2 gradient stops directly on top of each other (which will create a solid line division like you have- try and go to the gradient panel and drag the grey or white gradient stop and see if there is another one below it

Comment: With a clean shape and a clean gradient, this should not happen. Something is wrong with either the shape or the gradient setup, and we can't guess that by just looking at the picture.

Comment: Looks like there are two shapes - not a single closed path. But that's only a guess.